# if else using datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

| Nama | No.ID | Tgl/Waktu | No.PIN | Kode Verifikasi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alif | 100061 | 17/12/2022 07:53:26 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 17/12/2022 13:00:25 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 19/12/2022 07:54:59 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 19/12/2022 16:18:14 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 20/12/2022 07:55:54 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 20/12/2022 16:16:16 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 21/12/2022 07:54:46 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 21/12/2022 16:15:41 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 22/12/2022 07:55:54 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 22/12/2022 16:15:59 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 23/12/2022 07:56:26 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 23/12/2022 16:16:56 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 17/12/2022 07:45:28 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 17/12/2022 13:00:23 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 19/12/2022 07:39:29 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 19/12/2022 16:17:37 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 20/12/2022 13:13:06 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 20/12/2022 16:16:14 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 21/12/2022 07:39:54 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 21/12/2022 16:15:38 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 22/12/2022 07:39:02 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 22/12/2022 16:15:55 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 23/12/2022 07:41:13 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 23/12/2022 16:16:25 |  | Sidik Jari |

this table is just some of the real data,so from that raw excel file i want to make a app to output the waging system

[the lookup table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16l9WN1dQqnEIqad026rUUNoUEOVi4Ag-/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104401636803655793957&rtpof=true&sd=true) this is the real data, probably this can help

and i come up with the code below

```
# Install required library
!pip install xlrd
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time, timedelta
import openpyxl
import math

# Mount google drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Read the Excel file
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Book2.xls'
df = pd.read_excel(path)


# Convert the 'Tgl/Waktu' column to datetime format
df['Tgl/Waktu'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Tgl/Waktu'])

# Extract the date and time from the 'Tgl/Waktu' column
df['Date'] = df['Tgl/Waktu'].dt.date
df['Time'] = df['Tgl/Waktu'].dt.time

# Group the data by employee name and date
grouped_df = df.groupby(['Nama', 'Date'])

# Set the overtime threshold to 16:30:00
overtime_threshold = time(hour=16, minute=30)

# Set the late limit
late_limit = time(hour=8, minute=15)

# Iterate over the grouped data
for (name, date), group in grouped_df:
    # Calculate the total work hours and overtime hours for each employee on each day
    start_time = group['Time'].min()
    end_time = group['Time'].max()
    total_hours = (timedelta(hours=end_time.hour, minutes=end_time.minute, seconds=end_time.second) - 
                   timedelta(hours=start_time.hour, minutes=start_time.minute, seconds=start_time.second)).total_seconds() / 3600
    if total_hours > 8:
        hours_worked = 8
        if end_time > overtime_threshold:
          overtime_hours += (end_time - overtime_threshold).total_seconds() / 3600
    elif total_hours < 8:
        if start_time > late_limit:
            hours_worked = 5
            if end_time > overtime_threshold:
                overtime_hours += (end_time - overtime_threshold).total_seconds() / 3600
        else:
            hours_worked = total_hours
            hours_worked = math.floor(total_hours)  # Round down the hours_worked value
            overtime_hours = 0
    if end_time > overtime_threshold:
        overtime_hours += (end_time - overtime_threshold).total_seconds() / 3600
   
    # Calculate the payment for each employee on each day
    if hours_worked == 8:
        if overtime_hours > 0:
            if name == 'Alif':
                payment_each_date = 60000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'budi':
                payment_each_date = 70000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'adi':
                payment_each_date = 60000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'supriyanto':
                payment_each_date = 70000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'Edi':
                payment_each_date = 60000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'Tri Gunawan':
                payment_each_date = 60000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'Bayu Aji N':
                payment_each_date = 60000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            else :
                payment_each_date = "Name Not Listed"

        else:
            if name == 'Alif':
                payment_each_date = 60000
            elif name == 'budi':
               payment_each_date = 70000
            elif name == 'adi':
                payment_each_date = 60000
            elif name == 'supriyanto':
               payment_each_date = 70000
            elif name == 'Edi':
                payment_each_date = 60000
            elif name == 'Tri Gunawan':
                payment_each_date = 60000
            elif name == 'Bayu Aji N':
                payment_each_date = 60000
            else :
                payment_each_date = "Name Not Listed"

    else:
        if name == 'Alif':
            payment_each_date = 60000/2
        elif name == 'budi':
            payment_each_date = 70000/2
        elif name == 'adi':
            payment_each_date = 60000/2
        elif name == 'supriyanto':
            payment_each_date = 70000/2
        elif name == 'Edi':
            payment_each_date = 60000/2
        elif name == 'Tri Gunawan':
            payment_each_date = 60000/2
        elif name == 'Bayu Aji N':
            payment_each_date = 60000/2
        else :
            payment_each_date = "Name Not Listed"          
    
    # 

    # Add the total work hours, overtime hours, and payment as new columns to the dataframe
    df.loc[(df['Nama'] == name) & (df['Date'] == date), 'Hours Worked'] = hours_worked
    df.loc[(df['Nama'] == name) & (df['Date'] == date), 'Overtime Hours'] = overtime_hours
    df.loc[(df['Nama'] == name) & (df['Date'] == date), 'Payment Each Date'] = payment_each_date

# Calculate the total payment from payment each date and insert it into new column named Total Payment
df_total = df.groupby(['Nama', 'Date'])['Payment Each Date'].max().groupby('Nama').sum().rename('Total Payment')
df = df.merge(df_total, how='left', on='Nama')

# Print the resulting dataframe
print(df)

# write DataFrame to excel
df.to_excel(excel_writer=r'/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/test.xlsx')
```

from that code i want to add if else in datetime
so if date is any one of these

```
holidays_date = ['2023-1-1', '2023-1-22', '2023-2-18', '2023-3-22', '2023-4-7', '2023-4-22', '2023-4-23', '2023-5-1', '2023-5-18', '2023-6-1', '2023-6-4','2023-6-29',
                '2023-7-19', '2023-8-17', '2023-9-28', '2023-12-25', '2023-1-23', '2023-3-23', '2023-4-21', '2023-4-24', '2023-4-25', '2023-4-26', '2023-6-2', '2023-12-26',
                '2023-1-8', '2023-1-15', '2023-1-29', '2023-2-5', '2023-2-12', '2023-2-19', '2023-2-26', '2023-3-5', '2023-3-12', '2023-3-19', '2023-3-26', '2023-4-2',
                '2023-4-9', '2023-4-16', '2023-4-23', '2023-4-30', '2023-5-7', '2023-5-14', '2023-5-21', '2023-5-28', '2023-6-11', '2023-6-18', '2023-6-25', 
                '2023-7-2', '2023-7-9', '2023-7-16', '2023-7-23', '2023-7-30', '2023-8-6', '2023-8-13', '2023-8-20', '2023-8-27', '2023-9-3', '2023-9-10', '2023-9-17', 
                '2023-9-24', '2023-10-1', '2023-10-8', '2023-10-15', '2023-10-22', '2023-10-29', '2023-11-5', '2023-11-12', '2023-11-19', '2023-11-26', '2023-12-3', '2023-12-10', 
                '2023-12-17', '2023-12-24', '2023-1-31']
```

it will make the payment each date 2 times higher

how do i implement it in my code? I try try several times like

```
if date in holidays_date:
```

```
if (df['Date'] == holidays_date):
```

but still gettin error

Comment: This code urgently needs some kind of look-up table. Don't express *data* in terms of *code*.

Comment: _i try several times but still gettin error_ Show us what you tried, and show us the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed something strange going on, that I didn't have time to resolve. This works though. You need to import numpy.

```
def vectorized(t):
    if pd.Timestamp(pd.Timestamp(t).date()) in holidays_date:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df['flag'] = np.vectorize(vectorized)(df['Tgl/Waktu'])
df.loc[(df['flag']==True), 'Payment Each Date'] *= 2
```

Comment: where do i put it, is it in the grouped_df for loop?

Comment: In the end, outside of the loop. But I think you are the one to decide that. Do you need it inside the loop?

Comment: It doesn't work, i add the date that is in the data to the holidays_date and the output is still the same as before'

Comment: Well it should. I don't know how to interpret the "add the date that is in the data to the holidays date"), 

Add the line "holidays_date = pd.to_datetime(holidays_date)" right on top of "def vectorized(t)" to be sure, because I tend to think you modified something compared to what you submitted, which I cannot find the words to clarify to you.
You need to really tidy up your code though. Including the solution I provided which is not very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
holidays_date.append('2022-12-17')  # just for demo

df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx', parse_dates=['Tgl/Waktu'])
m = df['Tgl/Waktu'].dt.normalize().isin(pd.DatetimeIndex(holidays_date))
print(m)

# Output
0      True
1      True
2     False
3     False
4     False
      ...  
91    False
92    False
93    False
94    False
95    False
Name: Tgl/Waktu, Length: 96, dtype: bool
```

Now, you can add `pd.DateOffset`:

```
df['Pay'] = (df['Tgl/Waktu'].mask(m, other=df['Tgl/Waktu']+pd.DateOffset(days=2))
                            .dt.normalize())
print(df)

# Output
          Nama   No.ID           Tgl/Waktu  No.PIN Kode Verifikasi        Pay
0         Alif  100061 2022-12-17 07:53:26     NaN      Sidik Jari 2022-12-19
1         Alif  100061 2022-12-17 13:00:25     NaN      Sidik Jari 2022-12-19
2         Alif  100061 2022-12-19 07:54:59     NaN      Sidik Jari 2022-12-19
3         Alif  100061 2022-12-19 16:18:14     NaN      Sidik Jari 2022-12-19
4         Alif  100061 2022-12-20 07:55:54     NaN      Sidik Jari 2022-12-20
..         ...     ...                 ...     ...             ...        ...
91  Bayu Aji N  100084 2022-12-22 07:31:05     NaN      Sidik Jari 2022-12-22
92  Bayu Aji N  100084 2022-12-22 07:31:27     NaN      Sidik Jari 2022-12-22
93  Bayu Aji N  100084 2022-12-22 16:16:57     NaN      Sidik Jari 2022-12-22
94  Bayu Aji N  100084 2022-12-23 07:37:30     NaN      Sidik Jari 2022-12-23
95  Bayu Aji N  100084 2022-12-23 16:16:40     NaN      Sidik Jari 2022-12-23

[96 rows x 6 columns]
```